# How can I remove all spaces from file in Notepad++?

Tags: text, notepad++, whitespace

How can I remove ALL whitescape in a file, using Notepad++?

Example data:

```
;;    ;;;2017-03-02;8.026944444;16.88583333;8.858888889
;;  ;   ;   ;   2017-03-03  ;   7.912777778 ;   16.88583333 ;   8.973055556
;;                  ;   ;   ;   2017-03-06  ;   7.954444444 ;   16.88583333 ;   8.931388889
;   ;   ;   ;   ;   2017-03-07  ;   7.926388889 ;   16.88583333 ;   8.959444444
;;;;;2017-03-05;8.984722222;16.98472222   ;8
```

Comment: use replace feature

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To delete all spaces in the file, replace `' +'` with `''` (quotes only for demonstration, please remove them). You need to have the checkbox "Regular expression" checked.

To remove all spaces and tabs,  replace `'[ \t]+'` with `''` (remove quotes).

This works for big files, too, where the solution of @Learner will be tiresome.

Comment: Tnx for help but I can't replace all line in document, --> https://postimg.org/image/6h73jkqz3/   Maybe any format?

Comment: You should state that in your question. Which spaces can be deleted, and which ones can't?

Comment: for some reason i still wonder people don't use linux tools on windows.. `cat file | tr -d " "`

Answer (score 17):

No need for regular expressions. In *Find what* add a whitespace character  and then replace with nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> then press the down button before "56". Then <kbd>backspace</kbd>. You will see the cursor becomes big and then you can remove the spaces all at once.